# read specific substring with condition

Tags: java, substring

I have this from text file:

134.897 134.4565 135.134

I read them using :

```
  while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                    String x1 = (parts[0]);   
                String x2 = (parts[1]);  
                    String x3 = (parts[2]);
```

From the String in the text file :

```
134.897
134.4565
135.134
```

I just want to take the **different number** between these three number :

```
4.897
4.4565
5.134
```

Given more example :

Text file :

```
101.435 
101.423 
101.322
```

Number I want to take :

```
435
423 
322
```

My plan is I want to compare each number with others,

```
101.435//x1
101.423//x2
101.322//x3

if x1.substring(0)=x2.substring(0)=x3.substring(0)
then remove substring(0).
```

I want to loop this "if" condition until the substring are not same.

Please give me some idea, thanks

Comment: How come the results of your first example include decimal points while those of your second example do not?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. How does the output 4.897 4.4565 5.134 relate to the input 134.897 134.4565 135.134? Please explain more clearly what you are trying to do with the 3 input numbers.

Comment: @NickJ: It's the ones place, the decimal point and the fractional part, but it's not consistent with his second example.

Comment: @Jason Ah yes, I should have spotted that.

Comment: @doraemon, are there always going to be the same number of numbers before the decimal place? If so, how do you handle that scenario?

Comment: Sorry for unclear explanation,I have updated my question, kindly check it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's the skeleton of an algorithm that could be used:

```
List<String> inputs = ...;
int index = 0;
while (allTheStringsHaveTheSameCharacterAtIndex(inputs, index)) {
    index++;
}
List<String> outputs = takeSubstringOf(inputs, index);
```

I'll let you fill the blanks, which are very easy to implement with the methods offered by the String class, and loops.

Comment: Help me, it said cannot convert String to List<String>

Comment: `List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList(parts);` But you can directly use the `parts` array if you know about arrays but not about collections yet. Just replace `List<String>` by `String[]` in my algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't answer @Steve about scenario of different length of numbers, I'll assume you want to compare numbers according to characters order. Also, I assume that the file always contains three strings in one line, saperated by one white space.

Given this, I hope this helps:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FindDifference {
    static File f = null;
    ArrayList<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String>();
    static String x1 = null;
    static String x2 = null;
    static String x3 = null;

    private static ArrayList<String> getDifferenceList() {
        ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (x1 == null || x1.isEmpty()
                || x2 == null || x2.isEmpty()
                || x3 == null || x3.isEmpty()) {

            ret.add(x1);
            ret.add(x2);
            ret.add(x3);

            return ret;
        }

        int index = 0;

        while (index < x1.length()
                && index < x2.length()
                && index < x3.length()) {
            if (x1.charAt(index) != x2.charAt(index)
                    || x1.charAt(index) != x3.charAt(index)) {
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }

        ret.add(x1.substring(index, x1.length()));
        ret.add(x2.substring(index, x2.length()));
        ret.add(x3.substring(index, x3.length()));

        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            f = new File(args[0]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please supply file path.");
            return;
        }

        String line;

        BufferedReader buffreader = null;

        try {
            buffreader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                x1 = (parts[0]);   
                x2 = (parts[1]);  
                x3 = (parts[2]); 
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ArrayList<String> output = getDifferenceList();
        try {
            System.out.println(output.get(0));
            System.out.println(output.get(1));
            System.out.println(output.get(2));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

I made it SSCCE. You can use only getDifferenceList (supplying x1,x2,x3 as fields) in your code (delete "static" wherever needed).

**EDIT**

As I said, you can use getDifferenceList in any scope (including Android application). I copy this method separately, simply copy-paste it into any class you want, and call it passing the file path:

```
    ArrayList<String> getDifferenceList(String filePath) {
        File f = new File(filePath);

        String line, x1 = null, x2= null, x3 = null;

        BufferedReader buffreader = null;

        try {
            buffreader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                x1 = (parts[0]);   
                x2 = (parts[1]);  
                x3 = (parts[2]); 
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (x1 == null || x1.isEmpty()
                || x2 == null || x2.isEmpty()
                || x3 == null || x3.isEmpty()) {

            ret.add(x1);
            ret.add(x2);
            ret.add(x3);

            return ret;
        }

        int index = 0;

        while (index < x1.length()
                && index < x2.length()
                && index < x3.length()) {
            if (x1.charAt(index) != x2.charAt(index)
                    || x1.charAt(index) != x3.charAt(index)) {
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }

        ret.add(x1.substring(index, x1.length()));
        ret.add(x2.substring(index, x2.length()));
        ret.add(x3.substring(index, x3.length()));

        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, what you assumed is what I mean. Where I need to  specify my file? static File f = "textfile.txt"; ?

Comment: @doraemon: code the algorithm with a hard-coded array of strings first. Once you have the algorithm right, read a tutorial about IO in Java, use it to learn how to read characters from a file, and then apply the algorithm. But you should start by reading a book on basics of Java: variables, types. Assigning a String to a variable of type File makes no sense, and you should learn that first.

Comment: @doraemon, you need to specify the file path as a program argument, the way to do it depends on your IDE. Are you working with eclipse? intellij? You can also just modify the code and hardcode the path - `f = new File("Your\\File\\Path.txt");` instead of `f = new File(args[0]);`

Comment: Yes, I am working with eclipse.... still trying to convert this coding to be compatible with eclipse

Comment: 1. create a new class file named "FindDifference", and paste the code in it (keep only the package declaration). save the file.
2. Click "Run" button (the green play button). the output should be "Please supply file path."
3. Click the small arrow next to "Run", and then "Run configurations..."
4. "Java application" -> "FindDifference" -> "arguments" -> "program arguments": enter the path to your file.
5. Click "Apply" and then "Run"

Comment: Thanks @Elist but I run in Android application. Trying to change public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: @Elist Is it ret the final answer? and ret is an arraylist that contain that 3 numbers? because I want to save all these three numbers to text file then